# Power BI Desktop: Sizing Matrix Visual to A4 Page

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created a matrix visual in Power BI Desktop and I need to fit it to an A4 PDF Page (landscape format). Unfortunately the matrix is quite big, so I have to scroll vertically and horizontally to view the whole matrix visual and when I export to PDF, a lot of the matrix is cut. Is there a possibility to reduce for example the font size to fit it to A4 or any other possibilities just using Power BI Desktop?

Thanks!

Comment: No, .pbix Power BI reports are designed to be interactive, not to be printed on paper. If you want to use the reports printed or exported to file, then this isn't the right kind of report for the task. Consider using [paginated reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi) instead.

Comment: So it's also not possible to transform pbix to report builder?

Comment: Further, it's not possible to use paginated reports in PBI Desktop?

Comment: No there is no pbix to report builder convertor. Paginated repots are built in Power BI Report Builder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/report-builder-power-bi

Comment: You can write a paginated report against the Power BI Dataset you build in Power BI Desktop.